# Why do my tests fail randomly on Mocha (using typeOrm, routing-controllers)

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, typeorm, chai-http

I am trying to build an app on nodejs. Using typescript and libraries like [typeorm](http://typeorm.io/) and [routing-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers)

While the app's API server works fine when running normally. However, there seems to intermittent errors when running npm tests. The test usually hang up during the respective before and after mocha script. But re-running the tests usually result in success.

Example - 
[image]

and re-running right after yields a success - 
[image]

The app can be found [here](https://github.com/typewrite/typewrite)
and to make life easier, for those who are interested to help, I have created a docker image for the same. You can simply do a `docker pull shaloms/typewrite` and then `docker run -it shaloms/typewrite:test-image2` and cd into the typewrite directory and then run `npm run test`.

Are tests written wrong? or I have done something wrong in my code architecture? Or is this a bug in the ORM library.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: since the orm reflects the state of the database you have to make sure you are mocking the database correctly.

Comment: @Olian04 - I am not using mocks in these tests (prefer it to be an end to end test). Instead, am spawning a test server that actually connects to a test database and runs migrations & seeding before the tests using the ORM.